# AWS SDK for Java version 2 - HTTP Transport Configuration

Tags: playframework, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I cannot use the `netty-nio-client` with `software.amazon.awssdk - 2.10.33` as it breaks my application built in Play Framework 2.5.x.

According to the AWS docs, the Http Client can be changed 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/client-configuration-http.html

Are there any samples that might use Akka or any other async http clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Akka HTTP, you can use https://github.com/matsluni/aws-spi-akka-http

Otherwise, there is the client based on Apache httpclient: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/apache-client

Or, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/url-connection-client